# Where does Kali Linux mount smb shares

Tags: samba, kali-linux, gvfs

In Ubuntu I've noticed that smb shares are stored in `/home/{user}/.gvfs` directory. But In Kali there is nothing in this folder.

So where is the SMB share folder in Kali. I've searched possible places like `/mnt`, `/media`. But I haven't found it. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The location that SMB shares get mounted by `gvfs` can be very distro specific or GNOME specific (GNOME2 vs. GNOME3). The locations are often `$HOME/.gvfs` in older versions but in newer versions of `gvfs` the location has changed to `/run/user/<userid>/gvfs`.

If you're ever questioning where this directory is on a given system then use the `mount` command to find out where `gvfs` is mounting things.

```
$ mount |& grep -i gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

**NOTE:** On my system (Fedora 19) my userid is 1000.

```
$ id -u
1000
```

#### Is gvfs running?

The directory `$HOME/.gvfs` may in fact be the correct directory. Check to make sure that the daemon is running.

```
$ ps -eaf|grep gvfs
saml      1724     1  0 Jan11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
saml      1728     1  0 Jan11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/libexec//gvfsd-fuse -f /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

If a process like this is running and the directory is empty, then the issue is there aren't any SMB shares currently mounted.

#### Use this Python script

I found this mehtod which you could use to locate the directory corresponding to a given `smb://` path to a server + share.

#### Example

Create the following script, updating the `uri` so that points to an actual URI that you're attempting to access. I called the script `gvio_gvfs.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gio

# uri='SMB://server/share/file'
uri='SMB://tank/t'

gvfs=Gio.Vfs.get_default()
path=gvfs.get_file_for_uri(uri).get_path()
print path
```

Make it executable and run it.

```
$ chmod +x gvio_gvfs.py

$ ./gvio_gvfs.py 
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=tank,share=t
```

#### References

- [how to find a samba share's gvfs path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213638/how-to-find-a-samba-shares-gvfs-path)

Comment: mount command doesn't list about it, as I can see. :(
something called tempfs is there on /run/lock but its not what i'd look for right?

Comment: yes there are 9 processes under gvfsd. Within them, there is a process called;
gvfsd-smb-browse.
but there is no clue where that files stored?

Comment: @shan - If you're desperate you can use `lsof`.`for i in $(pgrep gvfsd); do lsof -p $i;done|grep user` this will go through all of them and look for strings with the word "user" in them.

Comment: that "lsof" shows gvfsd-smb -> /home{user}/.cache/dconf/user; and thats a file, not a dir. :(

Comment: the windows share is already mounted and I can access them, only by nautilus. May be its different in Kali linux?

Comment: @shan - yes I have similar lines w/ the `.cache/dconf`. It's not those.

Comment: and thats all it shows. May be there is a way to mount those smb shares to a place where i want?

Comment: @shan - I doubt it, I'm taking a look at the source code now for Kali's version of gvfs.

Comment: @shan - what about this directory? `/run/media/$USER`?

Comment: no directory named "media" under /run

Comment: @shan - what's the version of Kali?

Comment: it says Kali linux 1.0

Comment: lsb_release says: kali linux 1.0.6

Comment: It's not your username by chance? `/run/user/<username>/gvfs`? Also you could try this method for ferreting out the location. http://askubuntu.com/a/213618/17531

Comment: @shan - see my update, you could also try that script.

Comment: nautilus-actions attempt failed... 
currently trying your python script...

Comment: I'm sorry for this is getting frustrated... isn't it?
the script's out put is "None" :(

Comment: @shan - that's the nature of software/computer work. It's always frustrating 8-). You edited the script so that it points to your SMB share, correct? What does that string look like, I'm just curious.

Comment: uri='SMB://shandanjay/share'

Comment: also tried; 
uri='SMB://192.168.1.4/share'

Comment: Do you have this environment variable set? `GVFS_DISABLE_FUSE`? It's referenced in the man page for gvfsd.

Comment: tried;
 echo $GVFS_DISABLE_FUSE ; nothing

Answer (score 1):

in Kali 1.06, on the top bar, next to applications, click places .... then click on connect to server, change the type to 'Windows Share' and fill in the rest of the details to suit the network share, once setup correctly, it should appear on the quick list area to the left of the file manager thingie .... or maybe you mean in reverse?

Trying to browse to the Kali machine, which isn't the usual way the 'Penetration' scene tends to be, the quieter you are, the more you are able to hear .... so 'normally' it makes no noise ....